# Equivalent of C# .Default. in VB.net?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I found this line of code in another question here on SO:

```
Comparer<TKey>.Default.Compare(x.Item1, y.Item1);
```

I'm trying to parse this so I can convert it to VB.net. To start I tried one of the online converters, which produced this:

```
Comparer(Of TKey).[Default].Compare(x.Item1, y.Item1)
```

But that returns an error saying that Comparer has no type parameters. Is this because VisualBasic library has a Comparer that is stepping on this one? Or is it because of the [Default] syntax, which I have not seen before?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azhsac5f(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1 has some code snippets that seem to indicate it can be used without the square brackets. For example, Dim defComp As Comparer(Of Box) = Comparer(Of Box).Default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ensure the Comparer is from System.Collections.Generic**. And then you can write like this:

```
Comparer(Of YourClass).Default.Compare(x.Item1, y.Item1)
```

where x and y's Item1's are of type YourClass.

If the comparer you are using is not from generic collections it will show that error (Comparer has no type parameters).

Comment: If I may, what exactly is the .Default. doing in this case? I am familiar with its use for indexes, but not in this syntax - or is this an index of sorts?

Comment: It's just a Property - it gets the default comparer for the class type parameter you pass  in.

Answer (score 2):

That is correct, you probably have the name `Comparer` in scope that is conflicting with `System.Collections.Generic.Comparer(Of T)` that isn't generic. Check your other modules and imports to see if this is the case.

The square brackets around `Default` is probably there to ensure that it isn't interpreted as the keyword `Default`. But it's completely unnecessary here in this context.

Comment: Thanks Jeff! This does seem like something that might be a subject of a better error message.